# Where is the syntax error in this code and how to fix it?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmrD6.png)

What is causing the error here? If I'm not confusing anything, everything is done as it should

```
CREATE FUNCTION convert_temperature(temperature real, current_scale varchar DEFAULT 'Fahrenheit') RETURNS real AS $$
BEGIN
    IF(current_scale = 'Celsius')
        THEN RETURN temperatue*1.8+32
    ELSE
        RETURN (temperature-32)/1.8
    END IF;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Gives a message:

> ERROR: syntax error (example position: "RETURN")

I asked chatGPT where there could be a mistake, to which he answered me:
"There is no error in this function."

Comment: ChatGPT doesn't know what it's talking about. Postgres does.

Comment: Do check the docs on [conditionals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS). I suspect you're missing some `;`.

Comment: In the first RETURN, you have a typo TEMPERATUE instead of TEMPERATURE

Comment: No need for plpgsql, sql is good enough (and faster) for such a simple function

Answer (score 0):

No need for pl/pgsql, SQL is good enough and faster. You can also use immutable because the function has no dependencies on any table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION convert_temperature(temperature real, current_scale varchar DEFAULT 'Fahrenheit')
    RETURNS real
    LANGUAGE sql
    IMMUTABLE
AS
$$
    SELECT  CASE
        WHEN current_scale = 'Celsius'
            THEN $1*1.8+32
        ELSE ($1-32)/1.8
    END;
$$;

SELECT convert_temperature(25);
SELECT convert_temperature(25, 'Fahrenheit');
SELECT convert_temperature(25, 'Celsius');
SELECT convert_temperature(25, 'Kelvin'); -- fail
```

Answer (score 0):

@FrankHeikens presents a valid solution. However it should be taken a step further. It should validate each the parameter `current_scale` for known content. If the `current_scale` value is unknown then return null. Something like:

```
create or replace function convert_temperature(
                           temperature   real
                         , current_scale varchar default 'Fahrenheit')
    returns real
    language sql
    immutable
as $$
    select  case when current_scale = 'Celsius'
                 then (temperature*1.8) + 32.0
           
                 when current_scale = 'Fahrenheit'
                 then  (temperature-32.0) / 1.8
           
                 else null
            end;
$$;
```

The problem is shown with the test case/example:  

*SELECT convert_temperature(25, 'Kelvin');*  

It does not fail, worse it returns an incorrect result. (Guess it a philosophical difference on the meaning of a *fail*.)

---

Alternatively, you can provide a specific exception for an unknown `current_scale`. It does however require plpgsql.

```
create or replace function convert_temperature_e(
                           temperature real
                         , current_scale varchar default 'Fahrenheit')
    returns real
    language plpgsql
    immutable
as $$
declare
    res real; 
begin
    if current_scale = 'Celsius'      
       then return (temperature*1.8) + 32.0;
   
    elsif current_scale = 'Fahrenheit' 
       then return (temperature-32.0)/ 1.8;  
   
    else 
       raise exception 'Function convert_temperature invalid parameter current_scale => ''%''', current_scale
                   using hint  = 'Specify Current_Scale as ''Fahrenheit'' or ''Celsius''.'
                       , errcode = 'CV001';
    end if;
end;
$$;
```

See [demos here](https://%20https://dbfiddle.uk/vJjtFj42).